# DataGrid: How do I programmatically select a ComboBox item?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

The ComboBoxes in question are inside a DataGrid's column and have been defined as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Right Column ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Caliber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" DisplayMemberPath="Thicknesss" SelectedItem="{Binding Thickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

TIA

Comment: public List<Selectable> Caliber { get; set; }

Comment: The column deals with Steel Thickness. For variety and differentiation of programming, in this one I used the term "Caliber",

Comment: You may visualize my full DataGrid here (http://patriot.net/~ramon/misc/Disable-Inside-Combo-Inside-Column.png) My goals are (a) Pre-select a ComboBox item and (b) dynamically disable some ComboBox items.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for DataTriggers which can be set on Style of the ComboBox and depending on the condition the ComboBox can be enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBoxes in question are inside a DataGrid's column and have been defined as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Right Column ">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Caliber, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Thickness" SelectedItem="{Binding Thickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19493.wpf-best-combobox-tutorial-ever.aspx#DataGridTemplateColumn_CellTemplate

Comment: Thanks, Monika, but your solution seems to be for WinForms. I use WPF.

Comment: Edited the answer for wpf

Comment: how does this answer to the OP's question?

Comment: There are more complete answers in the Microsoft WPF Forum, here: (http://goo.gl/px3SPT)